# Multiple Constructor injection using Java Annotations

Tags: spring

The SPRING doc says the following

> Spring Framework 4.3, an @Autowired annotation on such a constructor
>   is no longer necessary if the target bean only defines one constructor
>   to begin with. However, if several constructors are available, at
>   least one must be annotated to teach the container which one to use.

As i understand if there are multiple constructors and we have not annotated any of them then i will get an error . I ran the following code

```
@Component // this is bean id 
public class TennisCoach implements Coach {
 private FortuneService fortuneservice;

public TennisCoach(FortuneService thefortuneservice) {
 System.out.println(" inside 1 arg  constructter");
 fortuneservice = thefortuneservice;
 }
  public TennisCoach() {
 System.out.println(" inside  0 arg constructter");

 }
```

I call that using the below code

```
TennisCoach theCoach = myapp.getBean("tennisCoach", TennisCoach.class);
```

But i  didn't get the error .I got the O/P as

> inside  0 arg constructter

Why?

Comment: Well, I guess having multiple constructors and not annotating any of them with `@Autowired` is the way you tell Spring you don't want any constructor injection to take place, in which case the default behavior (i.e. using the default constructor) is applied. You'd get an error if the default construtor was not provided.

Comment: i removed the default constructor but my code ran fine.No errors

Comment: If you remove the default constructor, then you'll have only one constructor, thus Spring will be able to create the bean with the only existing constructor.

Comment: yes i got now how Spring is working behind the scenes.Can you just provide the code snippet that Spring creates behind the scene.

Comment: @Rahul I meant the case when a default constructor is not defined **and** there is still more than one constructor available. Sorry I didn't make this clear. As for the code, you can actually see for yourself how spring decides which one to use [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java)

Comment: Yup I got it now

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the text you've quoted from the Spring docs doesn't apply to a case where one of the constructors is a no-args (default) constructor. You can see this very easily if you try and add an bean reference parameter to it.

Spring attempts to determine the candidate constructors using [AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) and in your scenario, will not find any single or autowired constructor, so it will record the no-args one and instantiate it in [SimpleInstantiationStrategy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/SimpleInstantiationStrategy.html).